How do I report multiple errors per file in Intellij?
I have a Gradle plugin, written in Kotlin, that preprocesses files with a custom parser. It is designed to be able to handle multiple errors per file and the plugin processes multiple files in a batch.
I would like to know how to log those errors in a way Java/Kotlin compiler errors are - grouped by files with clickable references and a readable list of errors as seen on the example below.

